# Resumable Online Index - sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

Possibly a bug in Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (CTP3.0) 
The DMV sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations with Detailed mode reports following

> Msg 824, Level 24, State 2, Line 1
>   SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect pageid (expected 1:457714; actual 0:0). It occurred during a read of page (1:457714) in database ID 6 at offset 0x000000df7e4000 in file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or operating system error log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

**Test Script**

```
-- Create table to hold sample data
CREATE TABLE Visits2
(
    ID         INT, 
    I100       INT, 
    I1000      INT, 
    I10000     INT, 
    I100000    INT,
    I1000000   INT, 
    I10000000  INT,
    IP_Address VARCHAR(15),
    VisitDate  DATE
);
GO
-- Create Tally Table
GO
CREATE VIEW vw_Tally AS 
   --Itzik style tally table
   WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
     ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
     ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
     ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
     ,lv4 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv3 a CROSS JOIN lv3 b) -- 65,536
     ,lv5 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv4 a CROSS JOIN lv4 b) -- 4,294,967,296
     ,Tally (n) AS 
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv5)
   SELECT TOP (1000000) n
   FROM Tally
   ORDER BY n;

GO  
-- Populate Visits2 with sample data
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Max bigint = (select ISNULL(max(ID),0) From Visits2);
WHILE @Max < 60000000 BEGIN 

   WITH TallyTable AS (

   SELECT n + @Max as N, 
      CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 255 as INT) + 1 AS A4,
      CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 255 as INT) + 1 AS A3,
      CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 255 as INT) + 1 AS A2, 
         1.0 + floor(1 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))) AS A1,
      DATEADD(DD, 1.0 + floor(62 * 
        RAND(convert(varbinary, newid()))),'2018-07-01') AS VisitDate
        FROM vw_Tally)
    INSERT INTO Visits2 (ID, I100, I1000, I10000,   I100000,
    I1000000, I10000000, IP_Address, VisitDate)
    SELECT  n,n%100, n%1000, n%10000,n%100000,
           n%1000000, n%10000000, 
      CAST(A1 AS VARCHAR) + '.' + CAST(A2 AS VARCHAR) + 
             '.' +  CAST(A3 AS VARCHAR) + 
             '.' +  CAST(A4 AS VARCHAR), VisitDate
    FROM TallyTable 
    set @Max = (select ISNULL(max(ID),0) From Visits2);
END
```

Open a new query window to execute

```
CREATE  INDEX NC_Visits2_1 ON dbo.Visits2  (I100)
WITH (ONLINE = ON,RESUMABLE = ON);
```

Open a second window to execute

```
ALTER INDEX NC_Visits2_1 ON dbo.Visits2 PAUSE;
```

Open a 3rd window and execute

```
SELECT  *
  FROM sys.dm_db_database_page_allocations
       (
         DB_ID(),
         OBJECT_ID('dbo.Visits2'),
         NULL,
         NULL,
         'detailed'
       )
```

The error only occurs when DETAILED mode is used. Interestingly, CHECKDB does not report any errors.

Anyone else getting the same error?

Comment: And ? You're using beta software. Report bugs in it to Microsoft.

Comment: I know it's a beta software but don't know whether others are getting the same error or not. If other people are getting the same error then worth reporting else not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce these symptoms using CTP 3.1 on Linux (Ubuntu). It seems the undocumented `sys.dm_db_database_page_allocation` DMV does not properly account for pages in the paused state during creation.

You can report this bug on the [Azure Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server) for awareness but be aware that it may or may not get addressed. Fixing this is up to the discretion of the product team since it's an undocumented and unsupported feature (albeit useful).